# Hace unas noches dormía/dormí bajo un puente

Tags: pretérito

La siguiente frase expresa que era algo habitual antes de la última noche, la que fue hace unas noches:

> Hace unas noches dormía bajo un puente.

Mientras que esto expresa que hace unas noches durmió bajo un puente una sola noche:

> Hace unas noches dormí bajo un puente.

¿Entiendo la diferencia correctamente?

Comment: Sí, es correcto.

Comment: ¡Muy agradecido!

Comment: Sí. Aunque, si luego se quiere añadir algo, como, por ejemplo _vino la policía_, yo lo hubiera expresado como _estaba durmiendo_.

Comment: En resumen, entonces, ¿esta también sería una opción válida? "Hace unas noches dormía / estaba durmiendo bajo un puente cuando vino la policía."

Comment: Para mí, suena mejor "Hace unas noches estaba durmiendo" que "dormía" para este caso en que se añade algo más del tipo "vino la policía", @rpax

Comment: @fedorqui a eso me refería

Comment: ¡Un montón de gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 2):

Es correcto, en el contexto descrito.

- la palabra '**dormía**' es la conjugacion del verbo dormir en *pretérito imperfecto* y es comunmente usado para referenciar la acción del verbo dormir  que se hacia repetitivamente en el pasado.
- La palabra **dormí** es la conjugacion del verbo dormir en *pretérito perfecto simpl*e y es comunmente utilizada para referenciar un solo evento del verbo dormir que se realizo en el pasado.

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto, pero en la primera frase es recomendable incluir la preposición "hasta" para facilitar su comprensión.

Si deseas expresar que era habitual dormir en la calle, pero no se hacía siempre; es necesario que lo indiques explícitamente, como por ejemplo:

> Hasta hace unas noches solía dormir bajo un puente.